# Can FGDC Status Checker be set to private?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, testing

I am currently using the FGDC Status checker to track the health and status of my ArcGIS Services.

https://statuschecker.fgdc.gov/

It works great, other than the fact that the test results and REST endpoint URLs are publicly available. Does anyone know if my account and test results can be set to private? Or of any other similar monitoring methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per an email from statuschecker@usgs.gov:

"There is not a way to hide mark a feed as private." (as of 9/19/17)

Hopefully this is added in the future.